# Loop something 4 times in Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to loop this block 4 times so it displays at the end the contestant who came 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th. Can someone help? List - `contestants`

```
total = 0

contestants = ["Vera Lynn" , "Billy Halliday", "Frank Sinatra"]
contestant_name = input(" What's Your Name: \n " ) # Asking For The Contestants Name

print("Judges make your votes\n")

for vote in range(0, 4): # Making A Loop 
   judge = input("Yes Or No: ")
   if judge == 'Yes': 
        total = total + 1
        print(total)

if total >= 2:
    print("Well Done ", contestant_name, " you have", total, "votes." +
          " you are moving on to the next round")
else:
    print("Unlucky", contestant_name, " you have", total, "votes." +
          " Unfortuanely you are not moving to the next round")
```

Comment: What's the expected output and current output?

Comment: If you want to do the whole thing 4 times and see who came in which place you have to restructure this quite a bit. A dictionary would be useful to keep track of everyone's score; some checks to make sure that a contestant doesn't go twice; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you are going for -- I agree with the others that this code needs to be restructured and that you should include current and expected output. That said I hope this will serve as a good starting point for you.

```
contestants = {"Vera Lynn": 0, "Billy Halliday": 0, "Frank Sinatra": 0}

contestants[input("What's your name?")] = 0

print("Judges make your votes\n")
for name in contestants.keys():
    print("judging %s" % name)
    for vote in range(0, 4):
        vote = input("Yes or No: ")
        if vote == "Yes":
            contestants[name] += 1
    if contestants[name] >= 2:
        print("Well Done ", name, " you have", contestants[name], "votes." +" you are moving on to the next round")
    else:
        print("Unlucky", name, " you have", contestants[name], "votes." + " Unfortuanely you are not moving to the next round")


# to place and print them:
placing = sorted(contestants, key=contestants.get)
for i, val in enumerate(placing):
    print("%s was number %d" % (val,i+1))
```

I understand this is very basic and has some problems but hopefully it will help you gain a better understanding of the basics. I recommend [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) if you want to learn more. Good luck.